# Can nitrogens in urea be protonated?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds

[image: Dialkyl urea group]

Is it possible in very acidic solutions for the nitrogens ($\ce{N}$) to get another $\ce{H+}$, making it $\ce{R-NH2+-R}$? Since it has a free electron pair, it might be possible right? If so, at which pH?

Answer (score 7):

Reagents/solutions that are acidic enough will protonate the urea group, just not where you think. The most basic site is the oxygen. Perhaps this is a surprise.

The lone pairs on the nitrogen atoms are delocalized (see resonance depiction below).
[image]

The oxygen atom has the most electron density. Below is an electron density map, where ${\mathrm{\color{red}{red}}}$ represents areas of high electron density and $\mathrm{\color{blue}{blue}}$ represents areas of low electron density. You can see the area around the oxygen atom is red and yellow, while the areas around the nitrogen atoms are green.

[image]

This image is from "The effect of intermolecular hydrogen bonding on the planarity of amides" by James A. Platts, *et al.* published in *Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.*, volume 2012, issue 14, page number 11944-11952, [DOI:10.1039/C2CP41716B](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C2CP41716B). The image is copyright the Royal Society of Chemistry and released under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported license.

Protonating the oxygen atom leads to a cation where the positive charge is delocalized (better, more stable).

[image]

Protonating one of the nitrogen atoms leads to a cation where the positive charge is localized (worse, less stable).

[image]

Comment: @4C0G about pH=0. "the equilibrium constant of urea monoprotonation can be given
a value of 1.93 with an uncertainty of about 5%." http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100135a013

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes but no. The nitrogen’s lone pair is in resonance with the $\ce{C=O}$ π bond. They form a π system not unlike the allyl anion. This is usually depicted for the amide case, but there are no significant differences in the urea case.

[image: Amide resonance]

Instead, the oxygen has an accesable lone pair perpendicular to the π system, so it is typically protonated first. This happens at low pH values; you typically need sulphuric acid or hydrochloric acid to get quantitive protonation.